# Git alias replace GIT

Tags: git

This is just for the fun of it given the star wars hype. Is it possible to alias the actual GIT command with something else like "force"? So when you do a git push you actually write force push or git pull you write force pull?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Any of them, but mostly on Windows

Comment: Did you mean `force pull`?

Comment: A symlink might be an option but I don't know if this would work from the bash on Windows.

Comment: for linux/mac: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias

Comment: On Linux, you can use an alias like this : alias force='git'. Each time you'll write force, it will interpret as 'git' :) You should write this alias in ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux/MacOS solution: Put this into your `.bashrc` to alias `git` with `force`:

```
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _git force 2>/dev/null \
    || complete -o default -o nospace -F _git force
alias force='git'
```

EDIT: The first command makes all the usual auto completion magic work with the new alias. Without it, tab-completion would not work, because the system doesn't recognize `force` to be a `git` command until it's executed.